# Ignore exception in Python

Tags: python, try-except

I have try-except block in python, and I want to do nothing when exception occurs. My code is as follows:

```
for i in range(len(grid)):
    for j in range(len(grid[i])):
        try:
            count = count > int(grid[i][j]) ? count : int(grid[i][j])
        except:
            //Do nothing here
```

How do I do nothing when exception is caught.

Thanks.

Comment: Please do not use `try: .. except: pass` - at least specify an exception type which you want to ignore! Otherwise you are likely to get hard-to-debug problems at some point when you don't notice an exception being raised.

Comment: If you are going to do this, I *strongly* recommend that you specify which exception you want to ignore (e.g. `IndexError`).  It's very bad practice to swallow *all* exceptions silently.

Comment: Is the `a ? b :  c` construct valid Python now?! I must have missed that...

Comment: @ThiefMaster: How to specify an exception type?

Comment: To specify an exception type just subclass the `Exception` superclass and make sure you have a useful `__str__` method

Comment: @hrishikeshp19 OK, I've left you a simple example to try out here: https://gist.github.com/1804191

Comment: @MarkByers : You are right. a ? b : c was not working...I changed that to if..else

Comment: Two questions in one? - Your question in the title, "Ignore exception in Python" has nothing to do with how to write a ternary in Python, right? Probably better if you separate them into two questions. You would then find that **both** questions have already been asked. For an answer to the ternary question, see [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator#394814](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809#394814).

Comment: Another option is `with contextlib.suppress(MyException): ...` which saves one or two lines(though not performance) and reads a little nicer IMO.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[`pass`](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-pass_stmt) is the keyword you are looking for.

Comment: theoratically you could add any expression *(e.g. `0`)* there, but `pass` is just more pythonic.

Comment: @NiklasR I'm not so sure. `0` is an expression and evaluates to `0`, `pass` is a statement. So, not exactly equivalent.

Comment: But the interpreter wouldn't complain. `""` was possible, too, etc.

Comment: Again, `""` is an expression. The interpreter may not "complain" as such, but if you aren't going to do anything with the resultant value I would suggest it's bad practice to evaluate it unnecessarily, if for no other reason that it's confusing for anyone reading you code.

Answer (score 10):

Let us write the code properly.

- We want to iterate over each cell of the grid. So **do that**. Don't create lists of numbers (`range`) that you iterate over and then use to index back in. Python's for-loops work directly with the container. It is convenient and easy to understand and good. Don't fight that.
- There is no ?: construct in Python. There is a `x if y else z` construct, but that is not appropriate here. You are clearly trying to set `count` to the maximum of its current value and the cell value. There is a built-in function for that.
- You really want the maximum of all of those cells. So ask for that directly; don't assume that you have to implement the high-water-mark algorithm yourself. You don't. (This also protects you from having to pick an initial value for `count`, which might be wrong.) We don't need to iterate with an explicit loop for this. We can specify the list of values to pass to `max` with a generator expression.
- You want to "ignore" values that can't be converted to integers. Notwithstanding that there probably is something wrong with your other code if the existence of such values could possibly occur in the first place: we can simply make a test, and filter out the values that fail the test.

Thus:

```
def is_integral(value):
    try:
        int(value)
        return True
    except:
        return False


# Now, get the maximum of all the integral values:
count = max(
    int(cell) for row in grid for cell in row
    if is_integral(cell)
)
```

Comment: Thats too high level for me right now. This is my first day. Thanks for suggestion though.

Comment: There is nothing conceptually difficult about this (btw, "high level" in programming generally means about the opposite of what you seem to think it means, although that's quite understandable). Writing the code this way is simpler than the way you're being shown how to write it. It requires **less** abstraction, because you aren't doing things like trying to figure out what this `range` object has to do with your original list. People who try to teach programming often have some very strange ideas of what's easy and what's hard. They teach things all out of order. :(

Comment: +1 for addressing the real issues.

Comment: +1 this makes a number of good points.

Comment: +1 the nicest and imho the most useful answer for the OP.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: I'd put `return True` inside the `else` clause of the try..except statement. While it doesn't matter in that case, it'd teach a beginner the proper way (put only the code that might throw the exception into `try`, the exception-handling into `except`, the if-everything-went-alright into `else`)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: I know what high level in context of programming languages means. In previous comment, by high level I was referring to complexity of "x for i in a for j in b" for a beginner. Your answer is great. Now, after using for loop several times, your approach seems a lot cleaner, safer, convenient option. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`pass`](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-pass_stmt), but also [`...`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/constants.html?highlight=ellipsis#Ellipsis) is synonymous in Python 3.x, which can be nice for writing psuedocode.

I see a lot of people use `pass` where they truly need to do nothing, while using `...` where they are using it as a placeholder.

```
class SomeInterface:
    def do_something(self):
        pass

class SomeImplementation(SomeInterface):
    def do_something(self)
        ...
```

This makes it easy to search for `...` and find areas where you have unimplemented code, without the false positives from `pass`.

Note that passing on an exception is generally a bad practice, as you will virtually always want to act on exceptions. You should definitely, at the very least, specify the exact exception(s) you want to catch, as otherwise you will catch all exceptions, potentially causing bugs you can't detect if a different exception rears it's head.

Comment: `...` is not strictly synonymous, although it will have no effect. It's a naked expression, like putting `None` or `0` or `"foo"` there. `...` evaluates to the `Ellipsis` singleton.

Comment: @ThomasK True, synonymous was a poor choice or words on my part. It will work as pass does in this case.

Answer (score 3):

```
for i in range(len(grid)):
    for j in range(len(grid[i])):
        try:
            count = count > int(grid[i][j]) ? count : int(grid[i][j])
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: That's always going to do nothing because there's a `SyntaxError` in the statement, and you're catching all exceptions.

Comment: @kindall: I don't think you can catch a SyntaxError that way; it should be raised at declaration, not during execution.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = x if a > b else y
```

Is the ternary operator

The do nothing statement is

```
pass
```